# How do I fix a 2 cm hole in tiles?

Tags: bathroom, tile, ceramic-tile

The tile in the tub enclosure developed a 2 cm hole near the floor.

I'll want to fix this, for aesthetics, to keep moisture out of the tub enclosure, and for safety as the hole has sharp edges.

What is the best way? Perhaps caulk, grout, or auto-body filler?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not just replace the entire tile?  Anything else will look bad.

Comment: while I sort of agree with CarlWitthoft, depending on the age/exposure of the other tiles a new tile would stand out....and could look bad

Comment: What is all the black stuff crumbled in the hole? It looks like you've got more than just a hole in a piece of tile. It also looks like there are additional cracks in that piece and all the grout is failing. You need to clean that up and access the damage, also, seal that off with some duct tape to prevent further damage.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "Anything else will look bad" the hole is small, at floor level and mostly behind a door. So I'd rather patch than replace the tile.

Comment: @JACK "What is all the black stuff crumbled in the hole?" Just dirt/mud  from the floor that accumulated over time.